# R: efficiently merge 1000+ variables

Tags: r

I have 1000+ datasets with the exact same dimensions and the same column a that I need to load from the web (using jsonlite) and then merge. I can choose the data.frame names but not change the data itself. I could do it all manually but there might be a more efficient way to do this. Let me show what I mean with this example of three datasets.

```
cola             <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
x0001            <- c(10, 11, 12, 13)
x0002            <- c(20, 22, 25, 29)
x0003            <- c(30, 31, 33, 38)
df0001           <- data.frame(cola, x0001)
colnames(df0001) <- c("A","B")
df0002           <- data.frame(cola, x0002)
colnames(df0002) <- c("A","B")
df0003           <- data.frame(cola, x0003)
colnames(df0003) <- c("A","B")
# data.frame names do not matter to me

alldata <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x=x, y=y, by="A"), list(df0001, df0002, df0003))
colnames(alldata) <- c("A", "df0001", "df0002", "df0003")
```

The merging to alldata and the colnames() function below would be veery long if I do it manually by listing all 1000+ variables. Maybe there is a better way, perhaps with a loop?

Comment: Where are the datasets? Are they already loaded in R? Are they somewhere in a folder? If in R eg above do: `nms <- ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$"); alldata<-Reduce(your_func_above, mget(nms)); colnames(alldata) <- c("A",nms)`

Comment: Are the values of `cola` always the same? If so, you will make substantial performance improvements with `do.call(cbind,...)`.

Comment: I actually pull in the data with df0001 <- fromJSON("https://...") and so on. cola is always the same.

Comment: Why not store them in a list when you download them? Like `jsonlist <- list(); for(i in seq_along(json_urls)) jsonlist[[i]] <- fromJSON(i)`. Then you can use `Reduce` on `jsonlist` and do `names(alldata) <- c("A", paste0("df", 2:ncol(alldata)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects are all loaded in memory, you can load all the objects into a list with the `mget` and `ls(pattern = ...)` functions.

```
dfs <- mget(ls(pattern = "df[0-9]+"))
dfs
#$df0001
#  A  B
#1 1 10
#2 2 11
#3 3 12
#4 4 13
#
#...
#
#$df0003
#  A  B
#1 1 30
#2 2 31
#3 3 33
#4 4 38
```

If the `data.frame`s always have the same columns, in the same order, you can use `do.call`:

```
cbind(dfs[[1]],do.call(cbind,lapply(dfs[-1],`[`,,-1)))
#  A  B df0002 df0003
#1 1 10     20     30
#2 2 11     22     31
#3 3 12     25     33
#4 4 13     29     38
```

Otherwise, you can use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by = "A"), dfs)
#  A B.x B.y  B
#1 1  10  20 30
#2 2  11  22 31
#3 3  12  25 33
#4 4  13  29 38
```

The drawback of `Reduce` is it results in significant memory allocation.